# Repository, Unit of Work, C#

Tags: c#, repository

Есть два интерфейса репозитория один для получения данных, второй для добавления, редактирования и удаления.

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class, IReadDataRepository<T> 
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    void Save();
}



public interface IReadDataRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}
```

Имеется класс репозиторий, где реализую интерфейсы репозиториев

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IReadDataRepository<T>
{
    Context context;

    public Repository(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
 ...
}
```

и Unit of Work с которым и возникла проблема

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private Context context = new Context();
    private Repository.Repository<Student> studentRepository;
    private Repository.Repository<Course> courseRepository;
    private Repository.Repository<CourseStudent> courseStudentRepository;

    public UnitOfWork(Context context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Context was not supplied");
        }
        this.context = context;
    }
 ...
}
```

Не пойму, что не так

Ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Т.е. у вас пару слов в коде надо переставить, но необходимость перепечатывать очень сильно мешает дать ответ :(

Comment: Извините, заменила картинки на код. Проблема скроется в написании порядка наследования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В записи

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class, IReadDataRepository<T>
```

`IReadDataRepository<T>` является ограничением "`T` унаследован от `IReadDataRepository<T>`"

Переставьте местами, так, чтобы он означал интерфейс, реализуемый классом:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable, IReadDataRepository<T> where T : class
```

И просто уберите его упоминание в объявлении `Repository<T>` - там достаточно только указания `IRepository<T>`, оно включает в себя `IReadDataRepository<T>`:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за объяснение и помощь!